# ASP.NET convert image from PNG to jpg

Tags: asp.net, gdi+

I am having a problem with converting the image from PNG to JPG. From jpg to jpg is very good but from PNG to jpg is having a pixelated problem. I've already implemented the compression method into this code but it still couldn't produce a high quality image.

Any ideas guys?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG";//convert toJPEG for web usage
         // Get a bitmap.
        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(@"E:\websites\LogoMaster\LogoID4.png");
        ImageCodecInfo jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        // Create an Encoder object based on the GUID
        // for the Quality parameter category.
        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder =System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
        // Create an EncoderParameters object.
        // An EncoderParameters object has an array of EncoderParameter
        // objects. In this case, there is only one
        // EncoderParameter object in the array.
        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);//SET to the highest quality
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
       // bmp1.Save(@"E:\websites\LogoMaster\TestPhotoQualityHundredp.jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
        bmp1.Save(Response.OutputStream, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
        bmp1.Dispose();

    } 
}
```

Comment: Didn't you ask this recently? Are you simply deleting and re-asking?

Comment: yes, there was an error in the question. Nice catch

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to redraw the image?  I answered a question on generating thumbnails recently ([asp.net version of timthumb php class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436209/asp-net-version-of-timthumb-php-class/)) that made the images nice and clean.

```
            Dim bmpThumb As New Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight)
            Dim g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpThumb)
            g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            g.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
            g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

            g.DrawImage(img, _
                        New Rectangle(0, 0, destWidth, destHeight), _
                        New Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

            '-----write out Thumbnail to the output stream------'        
            'get jpeg image coded info so we can use it when saving'
            Dim ici As Imaging.ImageCodecInfo = Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().Where(Function(c) c.MimeType = "image/jpeg").First()

            'save image to memory stream'
            Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
            bmpThumb.Save(ms, ici, BuildQualityParams(context))
```

Once you save it to the memory stream you just need to write it out to the asp.net response stream:

```
         context.Response.Clear()
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
            ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream)
            context.Response.Flush()
```

Comment: still looking pretty blurry. If I output as png the picture is looking sharp and JPEG is looking very blurry

Comment: GDI had to do something to make it "Web Safe" that is why the compression was terrible. There is some articles about "Color Quantization" but it only support version 2 and the code was a little too much. I have no option but to save the result as PNG with the white background to prevent problem with IE 6.

Comment: Maybe you could use http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/, a jquery plugin that makes png images transparent on IE6.

Comment: thanks, i've been using that but not anymore, thanks my new technique(adding white background)...lol